# Perl Regex Matching

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to perl and having a problem matching a particular portion of a string.

What I'm trying to match is in bold:

[1339300800] CURRENT HOST STATE: **Something**;

I was successfully able to match the String between the brackets, at least!

```
($line=~/\[(\d*)\]*/)
```

I'm trying something like this for the bolded portion:

```
($line=~/STATE:\s(\S+);/)
```

Could anyone give some advice?

Comment: [Works for me.](http://codepad.org/qri8rW48) What's the actual problem?

Comment: The answers you are getting are from people who have guessed what the problem is. Your own solution will result in a regex match with `$1` containing `Something`. What is going wrong for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex

```
STATE:\s([^;]*);
```

Does work for me. Remember that it is matched in group 1

```
if ($subject =~ m/STATE:\s(\S+);/) {
    $result = $1;
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Also, the first regex can be made a bit less verbose

```
\[(\d*)]
```

Comment: Right, then your solution where you consider ; as the delimeter is a good.

Answer (score 2):

If the statement always ends with a `;`, you can write:

```
$line =~ /:\s([^;]+)/
```

Comment: This is what actually worked, not sure why everyone was saying that my code was fine but I still couldnt get it to work, strangely. Thanks for this solution, though!!

Comment: @JackieAldama Everyone was testing with "something" but once that string had a space "some thing" your regex would break

Comment: In the end this has to be a Good Answer, so +1. But `/:\s+([^;]+)/` is probably safer. Or even `/:\s+([^;]+?)\s*;/`.

Answer (score 1):

You're close:

```
$line =~ /STATE:\s+([^;]+);/
```

That will get everything that's not a semicolon. Also it will still match if there's more than one space between STATE and "something"